# How do I authorize my handheld device to pair with an emulated android wear device

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, emulation, wear-os

I have created an android wear emulator in android studio on my Ubuntu system and have my galaxy s3 in developer mode and connected to my computer via usb.

following the instructions located [here](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html) I had to type the following into the terminal.

```
adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
```

but I get the following error.

```
error: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.
```

there were no confirmation dialogs on either the emulator or my phone.

Comment: You may need to enable USB Debugging option under Settings | Developer Option menu on your Galaxy S3.

Comment: this has already been done.